# Hibernate HQL bulk delete don't remove join table values

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I've some Jpa entities:

```
@Entity
public class Parent{
     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@OrderBy(" date DESC")
List<Child> childList = new ArrayList<Child>();
private boolean enabled;

}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Child{
    private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

I want delete parent and all childs with a bulk HQL query.
So as first thing I load all Parent entities I want to delete:

```
String query = "SELECT p.id FROM Parent p WHERE p.enabled=true";
    TypedQuery<Long> q = entityManager.createQuery(query , Long.class);     
    List<Long> parentId= q.getResultList();
```

then I select all childs to remove

```
    String query = "SELECT c.id FROM Parent p JOIN p.childList c WHERE p.id=:parentId";
    q = entityManager.createQuery(query , Long.class);
    q.setParameter("parentId", parentId);
    List<Long> childId= q.getResultList();
```

then I try to remove child entities:

```
     String queryDeleteChild = "DELETE FROM Child c WHERE c.id IN :childId";
    q2 = entityManager.createQuery(queryDeleteChild );
    q2.setParameter("childId", childId);
    q2.executeUpdate();
```

but at this point I've an exception:

```
     14/03/2015 11:39:38 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - Referential
        integrity constraint violation: "FK_K1BX38JRPVSWUSYJP28LBYGCN:     
PUBLIC.PARENT_CHILD FOREIGN KEY(CHILDLIST_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CHILD(ID) 
1751)"; SQL statement:
    delete from Child where id in (?) [23503-186]
```

I can't explain why values inside the join table PARENT_CHILD are not deleted.
There is a way to do this without use bulk **native** query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JPQL `Bulk Delete` will not cascade anything (that is the whole point of it) then this is to be expected. If you want cascading then use normal JPA `remove`.